# Hiding Navigation Bar in Tab Bar Controller

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, navigationbar

I have my app setup like this:

```
NavigationController
|-StartViewController
  |-Start2ViewController
    |-TabBarController
      |-Tab1ViewController
      |-Tab2ViewController
```

I want to hide navigation bar in Tab2ViewController but not in Tab1ViewController. So below is my code for Tab2ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class Tab2ViewController: ICPVC {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("View Wwill Appear Reached")
        self.tabBarController!.navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)          
    }
}
```

This does not work and navigation bar appears in both `Tab1ViewController and Tab2ViewController`, however, if I only switch the tabs' position in Interface builder so that `Tab2ViewController` is the first Viewcontroller in tabs, then it works and navigation bar is hidden in `Tab2ViewController` and visible in `Tab1ViewController`

Can't figure out why?

Comment: Does the TabBarController need to be inside the NavigationController?  If you only want it for one tab, why not put Tab1ViewController inside the NavigationController?

Comment: I am going to have a lot more viewcontrollers inside several tabs

Comment: That's fine.  You can still decide, per tab, whether it will have a controller stack that needs a navigation controller to manage it.  (The reason I suggest this direction is that I always find it difficult to fight against the behaviour UIKit prefers.)

Comment: hmm... but my other problem is that i have a few viewcontrollers between navigationcontroller and tabcontroller too, so i need navigation prior to tabcontroller too. Updated question accordingly.